# Subqueries to filter out in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

How do write an equivalent statement in RethinkDB using Python client driver?

```
SELECT id fields FROM tasks WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM finished_tasks)
```

This is what I tried:

```
r.table('tasks').filter(lambda row: r.not(row['id'] in r.table('finished_tasks').pluck("id").coerce_to('array').run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java Script:

```
r.table("tasks").filter(function(task){
 return r.expr(r.table("finished_tasks").pluck("id")).map(function(i){
       return i("id");
    }).coerceTo('array')
      .contains(task("id"))
      .not();

})
```

In  Python should be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example in Python. I give JavaScript example and I think you can compare on API doc to write Python equivalent.

Assume that `id` is also the primary key of `finished_tasks` table.

```
r.table('tasks').filter(function(task) {
  return r.table('finished_tasks').get(task('id')).eq(null)
})
```

If `id` isn't primary key of `finished_tasks`, let's create a secondary index for it, then use it in `getAll`

```
// Create index
r.table('finished_tasks').indexCreate('finished_task', r.row('id'))
// Using index for efficient query
r.table('tasks').filter(function(task) {
  return r.table('finished_tasks').getAll(task('id'), {index: 'finished_task'}).count().eq(0)
})
```